# What were the subjects of ancient Gurukulas?

Tags: guru, vedic, gurukul

What did children were taught in Vedic periods and why?

Comment: There is no source from which we can get information about this, but there is a reference from a book beautifull tree by Dharampal, which mentions about the subjects taugh in india during 1800 CE.

Comment: The Vedic recession as followed in one's family (Samhita, Brahmana, Aranyaka, Upanishad), Vedangas - Shiksha (method of proper pronunciation of Vedic mantras), chhandas (prosody), vyakarana (grammar), Nirukta (a dictionary used to interpret the Veda), Jyotisa (time-keeping) & Kalpa (rituals). The kalpa section includes shrautasutras, grihyasutras, dharmasutras & parisisthas of the Vedic recession observed by the student's family. Additionally upavedas -Ayurveda (medicine), Gandharvaveda (music), Dhanurveda (weaponry) & Nitishastra (politics & statecraft) were also taught.